# How beneficial to install DevExpress extension to my Visual studio 12?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, testcafe

I am using Visual Studio Coded UI as a test automation tool. Our project manager asked us to install a DevExpress extension to VS2012. I have been searching online but I didn't figure out how DevExpress will help us in our test automation path.

Comment: Have you tried asking your project manager?

Comment: Does your development team use DevExpress components? If so, you'll need the extension to properly inspect and interact with some of the components, especially in desktop applications

Answer (score 2):

If you are building a DevExpress desktop application with WinForms then you need the extension to be able to interact with the DevExpress components. CodedUI is very limited without it, it creates extra hooks for MS UI Automation framework.

If you are testing a web-application with DevExpress tooling then I do not think you need to install the extensions.

Also see the documentation: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodedUIExtension/CustomDocument11028

Comment: Thanks for replies , VS2012's coded UI component is enough for our project. It covers all necessary things in our GUI automation checklist.

Comment: @RecepC don't forget to upvote and accept if you found this answer useful. :-) It shows future visitors with the same issue that it actually solved your problem.